# regular expression javascript with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

I read on [RegExp in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

And I see two ways to create new RegExp:`/ab+c/i;
new RegExp('ab+c', 'i');
new RegExp(/ab+c/, 'i');`

But I want to create new RegExp like this:

```
var re = new RegExp(`\d+${variable}`, 'g');
```

I try but it's not working. How can I do that?

Comment: Please, leave the sample from your variable.

Answer (score 4):

Escape your [**RegExp character class**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes) in the [**template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with a `\\`, e.g. to escape:

- `\d`, write `\\d`
- `\w`, write `\\w`
- `\s`, write `\\s`

...and so on.

```js
let variable = 1;
const re = new RegExp(`\\d+${variable}`, 'g');

console.log(re);
```

[**More on RegeExp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 1):

You can write the whole expression as a string (to which you can concatenate the value of the variable), then use `eval()` to change it to a working javascript expression:

```
var x = "A";
var re = eval("new RegExp('\d+$" + x + "', 'g')");
```